# Java/Android Button functions do nothing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem trying to use setText and onClickListener on a button in Android/Java inside a fragment. The setText function seems to be working but doesnt update the UI. Whats inside the onClickListener doesnt run at all when pressing the button. So seems that the UI is disconnected from the code for some reason.

See below for part of the code for the fragment and the xml. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
public class BooksellersFragment extends Fragment{

private Button subscribeButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booksellers, container, false);

    subscribeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);

    System.out.println("This runs");

    System.out.println(subscribeButton.getText()); //This shows the default text
    subscribeButton.setText("testing");
    System.out.println(subscribeButton.getText()); //This outputs the new text but the button text doesnt change in the UI.

    subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        System.out.println("nothing here runs when clicking the button");
        subscribeButton.setText("test");
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booksellers, container, false);
   }
}
```

XML (Button part):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/subscribeButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Prenumerera"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookImage" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is wrong. You have to return the view you created above. So replace:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booksellers, container, false);
```

with

```
return v;
```

Comment: @user3658609 no sense to spend time helping this person - he is responsive when help is needed but leaves most of question without feedback. Lots of unsolved questions.